# Copying XML files to reuse in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to copy xml files to use the same layout for other screen?

I have a Monday xml file with Monday values that I want to make a copy and change in to a Tuesday xml file with the Tuesday values. However when I change the values in the 'Tuesday' XML file it changes the Monday XML file to the 'Tuesday' XML file values. I end up having 2 of the same file.... hope this make sense?

They must be linked i some way and not making a SEPARATE copy of the file when I duplicate it.

Anyway around this?

Many thanks,

Mark

Comment: Did you tried.. cltr+c, ctrl+v?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, please share your monday xml file. The point of xml files is you programmatically write values in them, so you shouldn't be needing two separate xmls for two days.

Comment: post code, may be you forgot to change at coding place

Comment: Please be more clear... it's difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: Just copy that xml file with windows explorer. Then edit in Android Studio.

Comment: `The point of xml files is you programmatically write values in them,`? Impossible i would say. @Onheiron.

Comment: so when i copy and paste the xml file i rename the second file 'tuesday' - this works. However when go change the buttonID that says 'mondaybutton' to 'tuesdaybutton' it changes. when i go back to my monday xml file all my values and text are changed to the tuesday values.... does that help anymore? @Onheiron

Comment: @Onheiron so when i copy and paste the xml file i rename the second file 'tuesday' - this works. However when go change the buttonID that says 'mondaybutton' to 'tuesdaybutton' it changes. when i go back to my monday xml file all my values and text are changed to the tuesday values.... does that help anymore?

Comment: @MarkWilliamson What I'm trying to say is that, to my opinion, you shouldn't be having 7 xml files one per week day, instead, you should have a single `week_day.xml` which represents *any* day. In it you should put elements like `TextView`s and `Button`s with general `id`s like `day_button`, `day_name` and so on, then from your code you go and set the values (the texts and also the listeners) to each xml element based on what day you're showing.

Comment: @Onheiron I get what your saying however I would much prefer using multiple xml files for the purpose of my project. Could you advise a fix for my issue?

Comment: What editor are you using for your task? It's seems very odd not being able to just copy xml files as separate files, also the behaviour you expect is kinda odd. Could you try adding an "empty" layout file named `tuesday.xml` and after that, just copy the `monday.xml` elements in it one by one?

Comment: @Onheiron yeah I tried doing that.... first just copying the file and changing the elements. Second creating a new xml file and copying the xml over but the same thing. It must be linked in someway....